# eloquent only apply where if column is not null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following where queries chained:

```
->where('start_timestamp', '<=', $activity->timestamp)
->where('end_timestamp', '>=', $activity->timestamp)
->where('minimum_activity_distance', '<=', $activity->distance)
->where('maximum_activity_distance', '>=', $activity->distance)
->where('minimum_activity_duration', '<=', $activity->duration)
->where('maximum_activity_duration', '>=', $activity->duration)
->where('minimum_activity_timestamp_time', '<=', $activity->timestamp->format('H:i:s'))
->where('maximum_activity_timestamp_time', '>=', $activity->timestamp->format('H:i:s'));
```

However, the columns may also be NULL. And if so, I do not want the condition to be applied.

so if `minimum_activity_distance` is NULL
I want to skip/ignore

```
->where('minimum_activity_distance', '<=', $activity->distance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` with a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping) for this

```
   ->where(function ($q) use ($activity) {
       $q->where('minimum_activity_distance', '<=', $activity->distance)
          ->orWhereNull('minimum_activity_distance');
    })
```